# How to load my own website files rather than WordPress site when I open my website

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I just brought a hosting space from GoDaddy and created a website using WordPress..

Now I have made my own website with HTML, CSS, JS etc. Now, I need to uploaded those files to cpanel file manager ..

But when I load my domain it loads only the default WordPress site rather than my own site which I created (HTML, CSS, JS)..

How to load that page by default instead of wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your domain first and then remove all default files and code from that domain path and make zip of your code and upload your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a .htacces file and edit it

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex first.html
```